# How to store data to use in Fully Convolutional Networks as well as RNNs?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

TensorFlow has a [parse_single_sequence_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_sequence_example) function, which is useful for feeding SequenceExamples (i.e. sequential data) into RNNs. However, for the problem that I'm working on, I'd like to try fully convolutional models in addition to recurrent models. How can I store my data in a way that enables easy piping of that data into both convolutional models as well as recurrent models?

To give more information, my data has the following shape: `[number of samples per minibatch, time steps per sample, number of features]`. Both `number of samples per minibatch` and `number of features` are fixed, but `time steps per sample` can vary (hence why I'm using a dynamic RNN). At least conceptually, it should be possible to reshape my data as `[number of samples per minibatch, time steps per sample, number of features, 1]` and treat this akin to a single-channel image (which can then be passed through convolutional layers). However, I'm confused by how I would parse data stored as a SequenceExample in a way that would let me do this reshaping.

Answer (score 0):

the answer depends a bit on the shape of your features.

For instance, if you have a feature of variable-length with a single float value per time-step, e.g. (0.1, -4.2, 3.0) for one example and (8.2) for another example you may consider storing it in a tf.Example.

You can then use the [FixedLenSequenceFeature](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py#L144) for parsing with [parse_example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py#L347) to obtain a padded Tensor. Continuing the above example with a batch_size of 2:

```
[[0.1, -4.2, 3.0], 
 [8.2,  0.0, 0.0]]
```

If you have a categorical feature that you would like to embed first then you should use VarLenFeature to obtain a SparseTensor. You may use it with tf.Example if you only have a single value per time-step.

If you have a list of values each time-step SequenceExamples are a more natural fit.

So, what should guide the choice is more a question of what shape your features have.
After parsing before input into a [convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv1d) or [dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) you will need to create a padded Tensor with a variable length sequence dimension.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I updated my original post to clarify my problem. I don't have variable-length features, but rather variable-length time steps. I don't believe I can use a FixedLenSequenceFeature, unless I'm willing to zero-pad all my data and I don't want to do that because my longest sequence is an order of magnitude more than my shortest sequence.

Comment: To get the input into the dynamic_rnn or the convolution you will need a Tensor of shape [batch, time, features] (batch and time can both be statically unknown).  At that point you have no choice but to pad. The FixedLenSequenceFeature with parse_example would do the padding for you (you may want to keep track of sequence lengths in a separate Feature). But with number of features > 1 you may find SequenceExample more intuitive to use. To reduce padding try [bucket_by_sequence_length](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/bucket_by_sequence_length).